# Fields are filled in with (unknown) after importing csv using fread in pydatatable

Tags: python, py-datatable

I have a csv with about 15 columns, this file is imported using fread from pydatatable.

```
dt.fread('temp_sample.csv')
```

Here some of columns are contained empty values i.e NAN's and partial entries and some other columns are completely NAN's.

[image]

Here country column is filled with (unknown) as it has no entries and whereas SSN has got NAs and entries existed.

Why (unknown) is filled in in this type of cases? Why it is not as NA's?

Comment: Do you have the same issue when you read it in pandas? If you open d file in a notepad, do the columns show?

Comment: No. Pandas reads it correclty and country column is filled in with NA only.

Comment: A sample.csv file would be helpful so one can download and test locally. You can change d contents of d sample to not match d actual data